# Can you add emphasis by ending a sentence with "even"?

Tags: grammaticality

Can you end a sentence with "even", or is considered incorrect?

- He even smiled at me.
- He smiled at me, even.

Comment: I mean in the sense I use it here. Not "The number two is even." ;-)

Comment: Yes, you're second sentence above is OK (by me, at least).  May cause some Pists to be pisst, however.

Comment: Yes, you can. Don't abuse it, though.

Comment: I literally can't even!

Comment: @Ricky. So sentence two is acceptable to you?

Comment: You can if you're [Snagglepuss](http://hanna-barbera.wikia.com/wiki/Snagglepuss).

Comment: What @choster said.  Go here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CAf5i4TEA0

Answer (score 2):

***Even*** is an adverb, so yes you could. However, I wouldn't intentionally try to use the word to add emphasis since there is an abundance of words that add emphasis without the possibility of confusing the reader.

Comment: Yeah, but what if you're writing dialogue?

Comment: @Ricky In that case, I wouldn't really know how to write such a sentence. Wish someone could post a sentence; it would be pretty cool to see.

Comment: @Ricky If you're writing dialogue you can put anything you like. Because it's reported speech any grammatical errors are the speaker's, not yours. Even if the speaker is a character you've invented it is still clear that the form of speech is part of your characterisation.